# How to listen to all errors in a servlet's request scope?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, error-handling, listener

My web-service has 3 `Servlets` that instantiate the same request scoped object which stores information about that current request like URL path, resources used and also **errors** thrown during it's execution. The intention is to log those errors and also send them as part of the response for the client, in JSON or XML.

I wish to use:

```
public class ErrorEngine implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
```

creating a class to catch all errors (with / without try in classes code) and then save them to a log file and also to an array that will go to client later. I did:

```
public ErrorEngine() {
    super();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    System.out.println("Error Handler Engine Started.");
}

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("Thread: "+t.getId()+"; Error: "+e.getMessage());        
}
```

and the *Error Handler Engine Started* message appears on console, but when I test with a *by zero* division inside the service() method of the `servlet` that instantiated the Error Handler, the message I created to test does not show up, only the regular stack trace.

So, How to correctly *listen* for all errors in the request scope of the servlet?

*I want to handle each of them in their own class and code, but I want to log them all from the same place, without having to call a method from my error handler class on every try/catch, even because errors may appear in places I did not handle the code for them, but I must see them in the log.*

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `MyBaseServlet` with `final doGet()` / `final doPost()` which call the methods `myDoGet()` / `myDoPost()` respectively (wrapped around `try{}catch(Throwable t){uncaughtException(t)}` ).

Every servlet should then extend `MyBaseServlet` and if needed override 
 default implementation of `myDoPost()` / `myDoGet()` or even  `uncaughtException()`;

Comment: So we need to user try even if we do setDefaultUncaughtException() !?

Comment: What about the error occurred inside classes with try/catch, that I instantiate in my doGet?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to implement another servlet that you can redirect exceptions to.  In that servlet you can process the exception and log it.  Unless the error is thrown, however, it can not be handled and logged by and external class, you will still have to have logging infrastructure in each of your servlets for caught and handled exceptions.

Here is waht your web.xml will look like:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ErrorHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<!-- servlet mappings -->
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ErrorHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type >
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

Here is a link to a full tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm

Comment: So if there is an error in /ErrorHandler, there will be an infine loop...

Comment: Is there an OO approach?

Comment: I need that the error data to stay in the same request scope. When I send it to other /uri I just can't send error info to my client as a subset of data sent by the service asked.

Answer (score 0):

> the Error Handler Engine Started
>   message appears on console, but when I test with a by zero division
>   inside the service() method of the servlet that instantiated the Error
>   Handler, the message I created to test does not show up, only the
>   regular stack trace.

You need to set the ExceptionHandler on the Servlet's thread, not the Error Handler's

See example below

```
package test;

import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

public class ErrorHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred in thread "+t.getName());
        System.out.println("Exception is "+e.getClass()+" ---------------");        
        System.out.println("Exception is "+e.getMessage());     
    }

}


package test;

public class ExceptionThrower {

    void test(){
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ErrorHandler());
        Object obj = null;
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExceptionThrower().test();
        System.out.println("After exception"); //this wont execute
    }
}
```

And this is the output

```
Exception occurred in thread main
Exception is class java.lang.NullPointerException ---------------
Exception is null
```

Comment: I believe I did this way, or maybe I did not use '.currentThread()' on setUn... I will check it out on Monday. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I do that before (in a filter chain)?